# Create Content with entities to link to another content's sub entities

Tags: entities, views

It's kind of difficult for me to phrase the question, but I'll still try:
My goal is to create several pieces of content that are referencing each other. But one content type has number of entities that can be referenced in 1 to many way. To be more specific it's an asset tracking which assigns asset to the spot within another piece of content.

Example:

**Content type**: Asset

- *Title*: Text
- *Type*: Taxonomy (Server, Router, etc.)
- *Size*: Integer (number of U this server occupies)
- *Rack*: Entity reference

**Content type**: Rack

- *Size*: Integer (number of u this rack can fit)

Details:
Asset has relationship to the rack, and based on the size of it, it'll occupy that specific amount of Us within the rack. When assigned to particular U, asset will occupy additional U's below it if it's greater than 1U in size. Those Us should disappear from selection list when creating another asset and trying to fit it into that rack.
Error must display if the size of the asset is larger than available adjacent U's in the rack.

Questions:
- What would be my best approach to achieve that in D7 and/or D8?
- Are there any modules available (paid/free) that already have this functionality?